# Running any scripting language from C++ service

Tags: python, c++, serverless, serverless-framework, system-design

We have a C++ web service that helps manage and run scripts for users. We have to offer 2 APIs:

1. RegisterScript API: Users can register scripts for a variety of languages(Python, Ruby, JavaScript etc.) through this api
2. RunScript API: Users can run their previously registered scripts through this API

Right now we’re not sure how we would go about this, any pointers would be nice but we’d prefer a solution that:

1. Doesn’t have to start an OS process for every RunScript invocation
2. Doesn’t rely on running shell commands from C++
3. Preferably there’s an open source library/framework with support for multiple languages out of the box?

Thanks!
Jessica

Comment: Hi Jessica, sadly there is nothing out of the box for this specific idea. you would have to create processes and have an internal NoSQL database for storage, then have some sort of either system cron job or invokationg system. good luckj